# Unable to add user CSFndRuntimeUser

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

Setting up instance of `Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 Update-2` in `Windows 10` with `SQL Server 2016` and `SSMS 19`.

Error occurred while running `Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1`

```
adding roles to commerceservices databases...
Attempting to add the user Domain\CSFndRuntimeUser to database SitecoreCommerce9_Global as role db_owner
**********************
Command start time: 20230524160916
**********************
PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-Sqlcmd): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)"

Error: Unable to add user Domain\CSFndRuntimeUser
Details: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
Attempting to add the user Domain\CSFndRuntimeUser to database SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments as role db_owner
**********************
Command start time: 20230524160916
**********************
PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-Sqlcmd): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)"

Error: Unable to add user Domain\CSFndRuntimeUser
Details: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
```

How to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Bit of a guess, but could you try appending ";TrustServerCertificate=True" to the value you are using for SitecoreDbServer parameter?

Comment: I tried like `"ConnectionString": "[concat('Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=', concat(parameter('SitecoreCoreDbName'), ';Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;'))]",` in Master_SingleServer.json but no luck.

Comment: Can you view the certs being used in MMC and make sure the Cert root has been installed under Trusted Root Certification Authorities. Also, if it exists, make sure CSFndRuntimeUser has permissions to acess the private key on the generated cert.

Comment: Try to create this CSFndRuntimeUser user manually then try, we also got this type of error but not able to recall the solution.

Comment: Actually, I tried that too, but the domain(comutername) is having spacial character in it so SSMS throws an error. I tried without domain also and its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you try to make an encrypted connection to SQL Server using a non-verifiable certificate. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/error-message-when-you-connect)

**Solution:**

There is a function call `AddSqlUserToRole`  in `DeployCommerceDatabase.psm1` at `\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.2.14\Modules\DeployCommerceDatabase\DeployCommerceDatabase.psm1`
need to add `-Encrypt Optional` parameter. Save the file and reset the IIS the `IISRESET` then run `Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1`

**Updated function:**

```
function AddSqlUserToRole
{
    param
    (
        [String]$dbServer=$(throw 'Parameter -dbServer is missing!'),
        [String]$dbName=$(throw 'Parameter -dbName is missing!'),
        [String]$userName=$(throw 'Parameter -userName is missing!'),
        [String]$role=$(throw 'Parameter -role is missing!')
    )
    Write-Host "Attempting to add the user $userName to database $dbName as role $role" -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline

    try
    {
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $dbServer -Query "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslogins WHERE name = '$($userName)') BEGIN CREATE LOGIN [$($userName)] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[$($dbName)], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english] END"  -Encrypt Optional
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $dbServer -Query "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = '$($userName)') BEGIN USE [$($dbName)] CREATE USER [$($userName)] FOR LOGIN [$($userName)] END"  -Encrypt Optional
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $dbServer -Query "USE [$($dbName)] EXEC sp_addrolemember '$($role)', '$($userName)'"  -Encrypt Optional
        Write-Host "     Added" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Error: Unable to add user $userName`nDetails: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

If intreseted in more details: https://sitecorememories.wordpress.com/2023/06/28/sitecore-experience-commerce-9-unable-to-add-user-csfndruntimeuser/

Answer (score 2):

As part of Sitecore XC9 Update 2 installation, in the DeployCommerceDatabase and AddCommerceUserToCoreDatabase tasks, there is a step to add the Commerce runtime user (which the Commerce Engine IIS application pool runs under) to the database as a db_owner. This seemed to be failing for me with the error:

```
Error: Unable to add user domain\CSFndRuntimeUser
```

First, I confirmed that the user in fact existed on the computer by running the ‘Get-LocalUser‘ command in PowerShell:

[image]

Next, look at the actual script at `SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.2.14\Modules\DeployCommerceDatabase\DeployCommerceDatabase.psm1`. The relevant function is `AddSqlUserToRole`:

[image]

By default, the script is trying to create the login from a Windows user. Since my SQL server is on a remote Azure VM, this won’t work because the first step of the script creates a local Windows user and it can’t be used for authentication on the remote SQL Server unless we add the user to Azure AD and then use that for authentication.

The other option is to modify the script to create a SQL user instead and update all installation scripts and JSON configuration files to use SQL authentication for Commerce instead of Windows authentication. By default, the setting is `TrustedConnection=true` which is Windows Authentication.

We went with the latter approach and updated the `DeployCommerceDatabase.psm1` script to create a SQL user instead of a Windows user:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $dbServer -Query "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslogins WHERE name = '$($userName)') BEGIN CREATE LOGIN [$($userName)] WITH PASSWORD = '$($userPassword)', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[$($dbName)], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english] END"
```

Here's the full source code for the `AddSqlUserToRole` function:

```
function AddSqlUserToRole
{
    param
    (
        [String]$dbServer=$(throw 'Parameter -dbServer is missing!'),
        [String]$dbName=$(throw 'Parameter -dbName is missing!'),
        [String]$userName=$(throw 'Parameter -userName is missing!'),
        [String]$userPassword=$(throw 'Parameter -userPassword is missing!'),
        [String]$role=$(throw 'Parameter -role is missing!')
    )
    Write-Host "Attempting to add the user $userName to database $dbName as role $role" -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline

    try
    {
        #SQL login
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $dbServer -Query "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.syslogins WHERE name = '$($userName)') BEGIN CREATE LOGIN [$($userName)] WITH PASSWORD = '$($userPassword)', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[$($dbName)], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english] END"
        
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $dbServer -Query "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = '$($userName)') BEGIN USE [$($dbName)] CREATE USER [$($userName)] FOR LOGIN [$($userName)] END"
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $dbServer -Query "USE [$($dbName)] EXEC sp_addrolemember '$($role)', '$($userName)'"
        Write-Host "     Added" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Error: Unable to add user $userName`nDetails: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Follow blog for more detail - https://sitecoredude.com/sitecore-experience-commerce-9-deploycommercedatabase-unable-to-add-user-domain-csfndruntimeuser/

Comment: I'm using a local SQL server. I tried to use it as suggested though not working.